# How to best modularize an Xcode project to speed up building

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, compilation

I work in a team on an iOS project that has grown to enormous size in terms of Swift code.

It takes about 10 minutes to build the project from the clean state and, most scrutinizing, 30 seconds to build and run the project after changing anything in the code, even if that code pertains to a single line in a private method in Swift file symbols from which are not used anywhere else.

We've tried lots of thing to improve build times, including techniques from this nice resource https://github.com/fastred/Optimizing-Swift-Build-Times
Nothing helped, you still need to wait the whole 30 seconds after changing every minor thing to see it in the app.

We use Xcode 10, the "New build system" with the compilation mode set to Incremental. If I build the project via Perform Action > Build With Timing Summary, the longest phase is "Swift code compilation" which is nothing new. We suspect that Xcode tries to follow conservative compilation decision making and rebuilds every Swift file that could potentially have any connection to the modified Swift code. And it seems that Xcode is wrong most of the time and does redundant work.

I kinda miss Objective-C days when the compiler would look at the all import/include statements and only rebuild explicitly declared dependencies, which meant blazing fast build times.

So I now think that maybe we could break our project into modules and ubiquitously use `import` in Swift to tell the compiler what Swift files depend on what other Swift files.

Is there a good and perhaps automated way to modularize a big project into many small components to speed up regular lets-try-how-it-works builds?

Comment: Well, if you've tried everything already which is mentioned by the article you've linked, then there is nothing much to do. However, one of the things the article mentions is also something we did in my current project as we we're facing the same issue (~10 minutes clean build time). We modularized all code we had into separate frameworks, and then link these frameworks in the main project. This way you remove the amount of code which has to be compiled in your main project, and you have a clear separation which can lead to discoveries of code smell/bad architecture.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans Is there an easy/automated way to modularize an Xcode project?

Comment: If you are a paid Apple Developer (sound like you are), you can ask Apple to look at your project. Login to your developer account and click Code-Level Support.

Comment: So are you using `Carthage`? If not, how many third-party libraries you have?

Comment: @Kamran Cocoapods, about 45 pods

Comment: So that is the real culprit. If you use them as prebuilt framework(Carthage), it will reduce drastically.

Comment: @DesmondHume, no there is no way to automate this. You have to manually do this conversion, and depending if the quality and size of your code base, this might take from a couple of days, to weeks. If you go this way, I'd also suggest using Carthage.

Comment: @Kamran Aren't CocoaPods pods already isolated frameworks/targets that don't need to be rebuilt?

Comment: No, that is what `Carthage` do but dependencies added with `cocoapods` are not treated as prebuilt frameworks.

Comment: @Kamran But project modularization means keeping the code intact. How do I modularize the project so that modules are treated as prebuilt frameworks?

Comment: Dependencies are already not supposed to be changed by you directly so no need to think about intact. Just use those 45 dependencies are prebuilt frameworks and see the results. I believe this will fix the issue.

Comment: @Kamran It will speed up clean builds but clean builds are not the problem. The problem is the slowness of regular lets-try-how-it-works builds.

Comment: It will affect both.

Comment: Good to read case study https://tech.wayfair.com/2018/10/ios-at-scale-modularization-of-the-wayfair-app/

Answer (score 1):

1. You can split your projects into Cocoa Touch Frameworks. -> https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios
2. Add each framework to its own git repo. It may be private repo.
3. Create private cocoapods. -> https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html
4. Add new dependencies to your project podfile. -> ***pod 'YourFramework', :git => 'FrameworkGitRepoPath'***

Comment: I highly recommend *not* splitting each framework into their own repo. Monorepo is far, far better for development and maintaining consistency. You can reference a file location for your pods, so you'll get the same effect but with one repo.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party here, but we are using this tool: https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/

Not only did it allow us to easily split the project into modules, it completely eliminated conflicts in the project file, because it doesn't need to be added to the repository any more.